# React render function not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, react-props, react-component

I have the following code - I would like to change the react component rendered on a button click. Clicking the button however does nothing. This is the parent class:

```
export default class SupportsContent extends React.Component {
  currentPage = "userSupportsList";
  goToPage = page => {
    this.currentPage = page;
  }
render() {
    let content = "";
    if (this.currentPage === "userSupportsList") {
      content = <UserSupportsList goToPage={this.goToPage} />
    } else if (this.currentPage === "chooseNewSupport") {
      content = <ChooseNewSupport goToPage={this.goToPage} />
    } else if (this.currentPage === "editSupport") {
      content = <EditSupport goToPage={this.goToPage} />
    } 
    return (
      <Grid>
        {content}
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

I have the following child component definitions:

```
function UserSupportsList(props) {
  return (
    <ListItem button onClick={function () {props.goToPage("chooseNewSupport");}}></ListItem> 
  );
}
function ChooseNewSupport(props) {
  return (
    <p>Choose New Support</p>
    );
}

function EditSupport(props) {
  return (
    <p>Edit Support</p>
    );
}
```

Comment: `goToPage()` needs to be manually bound to `.this` i believe

Comment: Read about [how to use state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). You can't just set variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React updates a component based on two conditions: If either the components props change or the state is updated using the `this.setState` function.

I recommend you edit your component to use state instead of a variable:

```
class SupportsContent extends Component {
    state = {
        currentPage: "userSupportsList"
    }

    goToPage = page => this.setState({ currentPage: page })

    render() {
        let content = "";
        if (this.state.currentPage === "userSupportsList") {
            content = <UserSupportsList goToPage={this.goToPage} />
        } else if (this.state.currentPage === "chooseNewSupport") {
            content = <ChooseNewSupport goToPage={this.goToPage} />
        } else if (this.state.currentPage === "editSupport") {
            content = <EditSupport goToPage={this.goToPage} />
        } 
        return (
            <Grid>
                {content}
            </Grid>
        );
    }
}
```